# Unable to place call in ionic for ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Cordova version - 6.2.0
Ionic version   - 1.7.16

I have gone through all the possible solutions mentioned in other threads , but nothing seems to work in my case .

Code snippet from my config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

Html file to place call

```
<a class="decoration" href="tel:1800-419-0333">
<button class="button icon-left ion-ios-telephone sr-orange-color">1-800-419-0333
</button>
</a>
```

The same code works in for android and a dialler opens up as i call on the button .

I have also added below code to hide underline to phone numbers

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8100"
    charset="utf-8">

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

This plugin  cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.3-dev " is also added .

Do i need to remove above whitelist plugin and just use href tag to place a call as i am using latest version of cordova ?

Comment: Have you try fetch error logs in IOS?

Comment: It is throwing me  < allow-intent> and <allow-navagtion> error .
I think i would be able to solve this from here . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Mention not... Happy coding...

Comment: @Naitik it actually worked:) , but ionic is directly placing call, i want dialler to open up everytime button is clicked . Is anything missing in code ?

Comment: Actully i am not getting you, you need to call from app with give number what you did already, what you want then?

Comment: i want a ios dialler to open up when button is clicked . Currently when i press button it directly places call without showing dialler in between .

Comment: that's why this plugin is used. one thing you can do like put one text box user can enter phone number then dial then places call on user inputed number,

Answer (score 0):

I had to add Below code to place call in ionic ios platform .

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```